# what is this dynamic object creation * []

Tags: c++, pointers

What does this mean? The following is a snippet from
[here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus-program-to-implement-hash-tables)

```
class HashTableEntry {
   public:
      int k;
      int v;
      HashTableEntry(int k, int v) {
         this->k= k;
         this->v = v;
      }
};
class HashMapTable {
   private:
      HashTableEntry **t;
   public:
      HashMapTable() {
         t = new HashTableEntry * [T_S]; //What does this do
         for (int i = 0; i< T_S; i++) {
            t[i] = NULL;
         }
      }
```

In this code, `t` is a double pointer and it is assigned to `new HashTableEntry * [T_S]`

Does `new HashTableEntry * [T_S]` mean the Object `HashTableEntry` is being made into a pointer to point to an array with size of `T_S`?

If it is, I am not understanding how a dynamically created object with the `new HashTableEntry` is being delcared as an `[T_S]` when the definition of `HashTableEntry` is clearly a class/struct

Comment: What does your text-book say about `new` expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t = new HashTableEntry * [T_S]
```

This creates an array of pointers to `HashTableEntry`. It creates `T_S` counts of them.

Perhaps it is clearer if written like this:

```
using HTEntry = HashTableEntry*;
t = new HTEntry [T_S];
```

Comment: what is the value of T_S? where it gets instantiated?

Comment: @RajkumarNatarajan the code doesn't show this, but `T_S` could easily be a global constant

Comment: yeap I see it in the code link. Thanks @smac89

Comment: This then create 200 elements of pointers to HashTableEntry?

Comment: @henhen indeed. Remember that a hashtable consists of "buckets" because hashed items could end up in the same location. Most of the time these buckets are implemented as linked lists. In this case, it looks like the author intends to use an array of `HashTableEntry`s. So each of those pointers will eventually point to a chunk of memory used to store all items that hash to that specific location in the table. Some implementations of hashtable will use a balanced binary search tree like AVL, or Red-Black instead of a list because trees provide faster search than a list would.

Comment: @henhen I just took a peek at the author's code, it is a very simplified/naive implementation of a hash table. Their `Insert` function has a potential to run infinitely if the hashtable is full. I would suggest you read a more practical guide to hashtables. I found this golden [tutorial](https://github.com/ppelleti/jsw-libs/blob/master/Tutorials/jsw_tut_hashtable.md) which is what I used when I first learned about hashtables. Give it a whirl